# Multiple Group Permissions on the same file

Tags: linux, permissions

Talking About Linux, suppose that :

I have a **file** and four users : **user1, user2, user3, user4**

How can I grant **Read** Permission on that **file** for user1 and user2 , and **Write** Permission for user3 and user4 on the same file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/352298/how-to-give-different-permissions-to-multiple-groups-of-users

Comment: What permissions should apply to other users? The usual way is to make a group for users that actually work with the file, assign those to the group, set `rw` for that group and `r` for the rest of the world. If you want more complicated stuff, you need ACLs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setfacl to do this without a group and set it to happen by default:

setfacl -m user:the_username:r file_name

setfacl -m user:the_username:w file_name

You can also check the permission via the following command.

getfacl file_name